# How can I run a function before my extension code in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift4

I am working on a project and am using a tableView to load data. The issue is that I need the number of cells to be determined by a specific function. My tableView sets the number of cells in an extension I added so no matter where I call the function, it still runs second. Any help would be much appreciate, here is my code (the function and the extension):

```
func setNumCells() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    let applicationReference = ref.child("applications")

    ref.child("applications").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print("So far")
            let array = Array(dictionary.keys)
            print(array)
            for i in 0..<array.count {
                ref.child("applications").child(uid!).child(String(array[i])).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        let array = Array(dictionary.keys)
                        self.numApplications += array.count - 1
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}

... 

extension ApplicationViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numApplications
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt inde xPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        tableView.rowHeight = 85
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `reloadData` on the table view and on the main thread after receiving all data

The recommended API to handle the timing is `DispatchGroup`

```
func setNumCells() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    let applicationReference = ref.child("applications")
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    ref.child("applications").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print("So far")
            let array = Array(dictionary.keys)
            print(array)
            for item in array {
                group.enter()
                ref.child("applications").child(uid!).child(String(item)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        let array = Array(dictionary.keys)
                        self.numApplications += array.count - 1
                    }
                    group.leave()
                })
            }
            group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
               self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Notes:

- `for i in 0..<array.count` is horrible as the index is actually not needed. See my improved code.
- **Never** create table view cells with the default initializer. *Reuse* them.

  ```
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
  ```

Comment: "Never create table view cells with the default initializer." ...if the cell is to be reused.